# C++11 QtCreator: long integer not correctly read into variable

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I have a singly linked list of type Node that is defined like this:

```
struct Item {
    long date;
    bool isPaid;
};
struct Node{
    Item item;
    Node* next;
};
```

Where "date" is a field that will take the form "ddmmaaaa" (that is, first two digits for the day, second two digits for the month, last four digits for the year).
However, when I try to add a few nodes, I get a different number inserted:

```
newItem=new Node;
newItem->item.date=01062016;
newItem->item.isPaid=true;
newItem->next=nullptr;
list=insertItem(list, newItem);
```

(insertItem is my function that takes a pointer to a list head and a pointer to a new node and inserts the node in the list).

I get the right number if I try to assign something like 13042016 to the long field:

[image: this is right]

However, when I try to assign 01062016, I get 287758 instead:

[image: this is wrong]

I'm not trying to use a different approach (I know the date thing is weird, I just need it this way). Only to understand why I get strange numbers when I add a date that perfectly fits in a long variable.
I'm using Qt Creator 2.7.2 based on Qt 5.1.0.

Comment: The use of `long` as a type is misguided. If you know you need, say, 64 bits, use `qint64` or `int64_t`. Basically if an `int` won't cut it, you need to use a portable type of a given size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `01062016` starts with `0` but not `0x` hence it is an octal number, it's equivalence with `287758` in decimal.

See [Integral Literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal):

> *octal-literal* is the digit zero (0) followed by zero or more octal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)